# Send a text message to android device with MAC address through internet

Tags: java, android, mac-address, data-transfer, internet-connection

If I know the mac address wlan0 of an Android device, you can send a text message to this device even if the device is connected to a network other than mine?

Answer (score 1):

No. MAC addresses are only applicable for a local LAN through switches, and cannot be used for addressing or routing by layer 3 routers or outside a local network. However, on an IPv6 enabled network, you can directly use the MAC address using a [link-local address](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-version-6-ipv6/113328-ipv6-lla.html#intro), or you may use a direct TCP connection if there is a program listening on the device, and you know the IP address and port.